# How to lookup for a value in the header

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

My headers contain types of errors whenever someone submits a new form he marks someone down in some errors which will be shown as a No in the cell below the error

I tried to do it by applying this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(A:A)=1,"Errors",if(len(A:A)=0,iferror(1/0),IFERROR(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,SMALL(IF($D:$EJ="No",COLUMN($T:$FK)+19,""),1),4),1,""),"1")),""))))
```

But I got only the first error

I need to get the names of the errors that was marked down
to be in a separate column named errors at the end of the spreadsheet and if someone was marked down in many errors it will be shown like this error1,error2,error3 ...ETC

Here is a spreadsheet containing some sample data 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SksZv0h82j5oEZBj2AN5anDFr80AYNR5ettSwkpUKys/edit#gid=0

Comment: pls provide example of desired output

Comment: I need to display the errors so each column has a No in it will display the full error at the header and if they have many errors like a no under Hold Procedures [Silence above 30 seconds to 1 min (NC)] and a No under Documentation accuracy [Updating wrong contact driver (for all contact reasons) (BC)] it will display like this Hold Procedures [Silence above 30 seconds to 1 min (NC)],Documentation accuracy [Updating wrong contact driver (for all contact reasons) (BC)] for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"Errors"; ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(D2:EJ="no", D1:EJ1&", ", )),,999^99))), ",$", ""))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your fast response but I have a problem here the equation is working but not for all row and not for all errors the main sheet contains like 4000 row and the range that contains the error is from T to FI

Comment: No errors messages but it is not displaying the errors  here is a sample of the data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BE6HMqSybnvo-9aun_o7oL63PJUspd6rhdLNhnOV_T0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much for your help